# $P(x=k) = \frac{1}{5}$ for $k=1,\cdots,5$. Find $E(X), E(X^2)$ and use these results to obtain $E[(X+3)^2]$

Tags: probability, statistics

$P(x=k) = \frac{1}{5}$ for $k=1,\cdots,5$. Find $E(X), E(X^2)$ and use these results to obtain $E[(X+3)^2]$ and $Var(3X-2)$

I know how to calcuate all these individually, but how can I use $E(X^2)$ and $E(X)$ to calculate the more complex forms $E[(X+3)^2]$ and $Var(3X-2)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$E((X+3)^2) = E(X^2) + E(6X) + E(9)$$
$$ = E(X^2) + 6E(X) + 9$$

As for $Var(3X-2) = Var(3X) = 9Var(X) = 9(E(X^2) - (E(X))^2$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- $\mathsf{E}[(X + 3)^2] = \mathsf{E}[X^2 + 6X + 9]$
- $\mathsf{Var}(3X - 2) = \mathsf{Var}(3X) = 9\mathsf{Var}(X)$